# Doxygen C# support about class overload on generic arity

Tags: doxygen

Considering two C# classes, overloaded on their generic arity, I mean: *same name, one is generic, the other is not* (but others arity variations may lead to the same issue).

```
class MyClass { public void Foo1() {} }
class MyClass<T> { public void Foo2() {} }
```

Doxygen [ver 1.9.1] seems to make a merge between the two classes, and finally, only one class documentation link is produced.

Have I missed something to help doxygen to discriminate entities ?

The *@class* tag makes no sense since the comment block is not external to the class.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: I've made an attempt with the ver 1.9.3 (last for now) but it doesn't change anything about that. My toolchain is defined on ver 1.9.1 but I would upgrade w/o serious problem if it could resolve the issue

Comment: Was previously reported under [git issues #8803](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8803)